# How to navigate to a route with parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm on a view with the current route:

http://localhost:4200/#/corp/projects/detail/05940c57/page1

And I want to get to

http://localhost:4200/#/corp/projects/detail/05940c57/page2

Is there a way to change to "page2" using `navigate()` or `navigateByUrl()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `relativeTo`:

```
constructor (
  private activatedRoute: activatedRoute,
  private router: Router
) { }

myFunc() {
  this.router.navigate(['page2'], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how did you arrive to the first URL, but assuming you have a configuration like

```
  {path: 'detail/:id/:page', component: ProjectDetailComponent}
```

you can navigate to it as follows:

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor (private router: Router) {}

  onClick () {
    this.router.navigate(['/detail', '05940c57', 'page2']);
  }
}
```

Comment: The configuration is more like: `{path: 'detail/:id', component: ProjectNavigationComponent, children: [{path:'revenue', component:RevenueModelComponent}, {path:'load', component:SystemLoadComponent}]}`

Comment: then navigate() should be called in the RevenueModelComponent